# Degree of a map when restricting it to a submanifold

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, differential-forms

Let $X, Y$ be closed oriented smooth manifolds of dimension $(n+1)$, where $Y$ is also connected, and let $F: X → Y$ be a smooth map. As usual, the degree $\deg{F}$ is defined as

$$
    \deg{F} = ∑_{x ∈ F^{-1}(y)} ±1 \; ,
$$

where $y ∈ Y$ is any regular value of $F$ and the sign is chosen depending on whether $F$ preserves or reverses orientation at the given point $x$.

Let $N^n ⊂ Y$ be an oriented, embedded and connected submanifold such that $N$ is closed as a subset of $Y$. Suppose $M ≔ F^{-1}(N) ⊂ X$ is also an oriented embedded submanifold of dimension $n$. By construction, $M$ and $N$ are both compact and $N$ is connected, so the degree of the restriction $\tilde{F} ≔ F|_M: M → N$ is well-defined. Is there anything that can be said about the degree of $\tilde{F}$? Do we have $\deg{\tilde{F}} = ± \deg{F}$? Notice that if $y \in Y$ is a regular value of $F$ (and thus of $\tilde{F}$) **and happens to lie in $N$**, then $F^{-1}(y) = \tilde{F}^{-1}(y)$ and the claim that $\deg{\tilde{F}} = \pm \deg{F}$ follows if it can be shown that:

> Let $x \in F^{-1}(y) = \tilde{F}^{-1}(y)$. Then $F$ is orientation-preserving at $x$ if and only if $\tilde{F}$ is orientation-preserving (or orientation-reversing – in the case of the minus sign).

If it helps, I'm particularly interested in the special case where $X, Y$ are Riemannian manifolds and $M$ and $N$ are constructed as follows: Let $p: Y → ℝ$ be a smooth map and suppose $t ∈ ℝ$ is a regular value of both $p$ and $p ∘ F$. Then define $N ≔ p^{-1}(t)$ and $M ≔ F^{-1}(t) = (p ∘ F)^{-1}(t)$ and assume that $N$ is connected. Note that $N$ and $M$ are automatically two-sided (and thus oriented) because the gradients of $p$ and $p ∘ F$ give rise to a trivialization of their normal bundles.

My issue in proving the claim even in this special case is that I'm having trouble relating the normal vectors on $M$ and $N$ to each other as I don't know what $F$ and the two Riemannian metrics are doing.

Comment: It is not so clear what $N$ is. Is it a given submanifold of $Y$ from where you define $p$ or is it the inverse image of $p$ as a map? In this case is $p$ defined on $Y$ I guess... My hunch is that since $\tilde{F}$ is a restriction of $F$ then its degree will just be the restriction in the definition to the sum $x \in \tilde{F}^{-1}(y)$.  

Remember that degree of a compsotion is the product of the degrees so $p$ will also affect it.

Comment: @Axstroo I apologize, there was a typo. $p$ is supposed to be a map on $Y$, of course.

Comment: As for your hunch, if $y \in Y$ is a regular value of $F$ and happens to lie in $N$, then $\tilde{F}^{-1}(y) = F^{-1}(y)$. This is why I suspect that $\deg{\tilde{F}} = \deg{F}$. As for the degree of compositions: I'm not sure I'm following you. $N$ is in general not 1-dimensional, so, unless I'm missing something, the degree of $p$ is not defined.

Comment: I mean that if you start from an arbitrary real $t$ it may have several preimages lying on $N$.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand. $N$ is *defined* to be the preimage of $t$ under $p$, so $N$ will be a codimension-1 submanifold in $Y$ for almost every $t$ by Sard's theorem and the regular-value theorem. So of course $t$ will have "quite a few" preimages in $N$, unless of course $Y$ is 1-dimensional. :)

Comment: Sure, you're totally right. I got carried away thinking on how I usually find degrees ''manually'' but of course we have no pile of disks in this set up. My bad, sorry :)
(edit: this obvious fact now pointed out only stregthens my original hunch since all that matters is actually how $F$ acts between $M$ and $N$).

Comment: In general, the degrees certainly need not be equal. Visualize, for example, the case where $F$ is a branched double-cover branched along the hypersurface $M$. Then we would have $\deg\tilde F = 1$ but $\deg F = 2$ or $0$. (Note, in particular, that no points of $N$ are in this case regular values of $F$.)

Comment: Note that to define $\deg\tilde{F}$ you have to _pick_ an orientation of $M$.  If $M$ is disconnected, then the choice of orientation can do more than just flip the sign of $\deg\tilde{F}$, since you can pick the orientations for different components of $M$ separately.

Comment: @EricWofsey Good point. So this means the orientation on $M$ definitely needs to be induced by that on $N$ somehow. Good thing that this does seem to be fulfilled in the particular case I'm interested in, where $N$ is given as a level set. I think in this case things work out as expected – I'll post the proof in a bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there anything that can be said about the degree of $\tilde{F}$? Do we have $\deg \tilde{F} = \pm \deg{F}$?

I will show below that without further assumptions, the answer to this is no.

> For each $n\in \mathbb{Z}$, there is a smooth map $F:S^2\rightarrow S^2$ of degree $0$ for which the restriction to the equator $\tilde{F}:S^1\rightarrow S^1$ has degree $n$.

If $p:S^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is the height function, then $N = S^1 = p^{-1}(0)$, and $0$ is a regular value for $p$.  But $0$ will not be a regular value of $p\circ F$, so this doesn't answer your specific case of interest.

The map $F$ is constructed as a composition $S^ 2\xrightarrow{f} D^2\xrightarrow{\rho_n} D^2\xrightarrow{g} S^2$.

The map $f$ is projection from $S^2\subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ to the unit disk in $\mathbb{R}^2$.  In terms of coordinates, it is $f(x,y,z) = (x,y)$.  When restricted to the equatorial $S^1 = \{(x,y,z)\in S^2: z = 0\}$, $f|_{S^1}:S^1\rightarrow S^1$ is the identity map (so has degree $1$).

The map $\rho_n$ is a $n$-fold rotation.  In polar coordinates, it is $\rho_n(r,\theta) = (r, n\theta)$.  When restricted to $S^1$, it is the canonical degree $n$ self-map of $S^1$.

The map $g$ maps $D^2$ to the northern hemisphere of $S^2$.  In coordinates, it is $g(x,y) = (x,y,\sqrt{1-x^2 - y^2})$.  When restricted to $S^1$, it is the identity map, so degree $1$.

Viewed as a map from $S^1$ to itself, the degree is $\deg(f)\deg(\rho_n)\deg(g) = n$.  Viewed as a map from $S^2$ to itself, it is not surjective, so has degree $0$.

Comment: For what it's worth, this example was constructed by purposely avoiding regular values:  every $S^1\subseteq S^2 = X$ is a critical point!  I agree (but don't know how to prove) that using regular points should give you a lot more control.

Comment: $g$ is not smooth, though.  You can fix this by changing $g$ to $(cx,cy,\sqrt{1-c^2x^2-c^2y^2}$ for some $c\in(0,1)$ (and then $N$ will be a different circle from the equator).

Comment: @JasonDeVito Great counterexample, thank you!

Comment: @Eric:. Good point and nice fix.

Comment: Great example guys. Makes want to cry a bit while noticing that this project and lift set up appears regularly in counterexamples. Thanks for thy wisdom n.n

Comment: @JasonDeVito I think I've managed to give a general answer to my question which carefully rules out counterexamples like yours, see my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

While Jason DeVito posted a nice counterexample to my question in the
general case, I've managed to prove the special case I was interested
in:

> Let $X^{n+1}, Y^{n+1}$ be smooth, compact and oriented manifolds, with
>   $Y$ also being connected, and $F: X → Y$ be a smooth map. Clearly, the
>   degree $\deg{F}$ of $F$ is well-defined.
>
> Let $p: Y → ℝ$ be another smooth map and suppose $t ∈ ℝ$ is a regular
>   value of both $p$ and $p ∘ F$. (By Sard's theorem this is fulfilled
>   for almost every $t$ in $ℝ$.) Define $N ≔ p^{-1}(t)$ and $M ≔ (p ∘ F)^{-1}(t) = F^{-1}(N)$. By the regular-value theorem, $N$ and $M$ are
>   embedded submanifolds of codimension 1. Furthermore, they are compact
>   and – as will be shown – they can be oriented canonically. Assume now
>   in addition that $N$ is connected. Then the degree of $\tilde{F} ≔ F|_M: M → N$ is well-defined and $\deg{\tilde{F}} = \deg{F}$.

**Idea:** As mentioned before, the proof is based on the following
insight: Suppose for a second that $y ∈ N$ is not only a regular value
of $\tilde{F}$ but also of $F$. Then, since $\tilde{F}^{-1}(y) =
F^{-1}(y)$,

$$
\begin{align}
  \deg{\tilde{F}} &= ∑_{x ∈ \tilde{F}^{-1}(y)} σ_x(\tilde{F}) = ∑_{x ∈ F^{-1}(y)} σ_x(\tilde{F}) \\
  \deg{F} &= ∑_{x ∈ F^{-1}(y)} σ_x(F)
  \; ,
\end{align}
$$

where $\sigma_x(F) = \pm 1$ depending on whether $F$ preserves or flips the orientation at $x$. So the claim follows if it can be shown that $σ_x(\tilde{F}) = σ_x(F)$ for all $x ∈ F^{-1}(y)$, i.e. that $\tilde{F}$ is
orientation-preserving at $x$ if and only if $F$ is.

**Preliminaries:** To carry out the proof, equip both $X$ and $Y$ with
some Riemannian metric (which exists by a partition-of-unity
argument). Let $ν$ be the normal vector field on $M$ defined as

$$
  \DeclareMathOperator{\grad}{grad}
  ν ≔ \grad(p ∘ F)
  \; .
$$

Notice that, since $ν ≠ 0$ everywhere on $M$, this provides a
trivialization of the normal bundle of $M$ (put differently, $M$ is
two-sided), and so $X$ induces an orientation on $M$ in the usual way:
For any $x ∈ M$, a basis $e_1, …, e_n$ of $T_x M$ is called positively
oriented if and only if $e_1, …, e_n, ν$ is a positively oriented
basis of the restricted bundle $T_x X$. Similarly, $N$ inherits an
orientation from $Y$ by considering its normal vector field
$\grad{p}$.

Since $Y$ is oriented, there exists a differential form $ω ∈
Ω^{n+1}(Y)$ of top degree such that $ω ≠ 0$ everywhere and $ω(v_1, …,
v_{n+1}) > 0$ for every basis $(v_1, …, v_{n+1})$ of $TY$ which is
positively oriented. Again, by definition of the induced orientation
on $N$, the $n$-form $\tilde{ω} ∈ Ω^n(N)$, defined as

$$
  \tilde{ω}(·, …, ·) ≔ ω(·, …, ·, \grad{p})
  \; ,
$$

is the nowhere vanishing top-form associated with the orientation on
$N$.

**Step 1:** Compute at any $x ∈ M$:

$$
\begin{align}
  ⟨F_* ν |_x, \grad{p}|_{F(x)}⟩
    &= dp(F_* ν) = dp(F_* \grad(p ∘ F)) \\
    &= [F_* \grad(p ∘ F)](p) \\
    &= [\grad(p ∘ F)](p ∘ F) \\
    &= ⟨\grad(p ∘ F), \grad(p ∘ F)⟩ \\
    &= ‖\grad(p ∘ F)‖² > 0
\end{align}
$$

since $M = (p ∘ F)^{-1}(t)$ and $t$ was a regular value of $p ∘ F$. In
particular, this implies that $F_* ν ≠ 0$ everywhere and so if $D_x
\tilde{F} = D_x F\big|_{T_xM}$ has full rank, $D_x F$ will have full rank,
too. Hence, **if $y ∈ N$ is a regular value of $\tilde{F}$, it will be a
regular value of $F$, too**. Moreover, this shows that the orientations
on $M$ and $N$ given by the gradient fields (which depend on the
previously chosen Riemannian metrics) are in fact *independent* of the
choice of metric.

**Step 2:** So let $y ∈ N$ now be a regular value of
$\tilde{F}$ and therefore, by the previous step, also of $F$, and let
$x ∈ F^{-1}(y) ∈ M$. Suppose $(e_1, …, e_n)$ is any oriented basis of
$T_x M$ (so that $(e_1, …, e_n, ν)$ is an oriented basis of $T_x X$).
Due to the regular-value property, $(F_* e_1, …, F_* e_n)$ is a basis of
$T_y N$ and so $(F_* e_1, …, F_* e_n, \grad{p})$ is a basis of $T_y Y$.
Write

$$
  F_* ν = ∑_i V^i F_* e_i + W \grad{p}
$$

for some $V^1, …, V^n, W ∈ ℝ$. Since $\grad{p} ∈ (T_y N)^⟂$ and $F_*
e_i = \tilde{F}_* e_i ∈ T_y N$, it follows that

$$
  W = \frac{1}{‖\grad{p}‖²} ⟨F_* ν, \grad{p}⟩
  \; ,
$$

where $⟨F_* ν, \grad{p}⟩ > 0$ as shown previously. Compute:

$$
\begin{align}
  ω(F_* e_1, …, F_* e_n, F_* ν)
    &= W · ω(F_* e_1, …, F_* e_n, \grad{p}) \\
    &= W · \tilde{ω}(\tilde{F}_* e_1, …, \tilde{F}_* e_n)
  \; .
\end{align}
$$

Therefore, $ω(F_* e_1, …, F_* e_n, F_* ν)$ and $\tilde{ω}(\tilde{F}_*
e_1, …, \tilde{F}_* e_n)$ have the same sign. Put differently, $(F_*
e_1, …, F_* e_n, F_* ν)$ is an oriented basis of $T_y Y$ if and only
if $(\tilde{F}_* e_1, …, \tilde{F}_* e_n)$ is one for $T_y N$. This
proves the claim.

**Side note:** $p$ need not be defined on all of $Y$. It suffices for it to be defined on some open set $U \subset Y$ and to demand that $N \subset U$ still be compact. To see that the proof still goes through, simply replace all occurrences of $p ∘ F$ above with $p ∘ F_U$ where $F_U ≔ F|_{F^{-1}(U)}$.

Answer (score 1):

A good night's sleep later, I think I can give the most general answer to my question. As it turns out, the particular case I was interested in is actually quite general.

> Let $X^{n+1}, Y^{n+1}$ be smooth, closed and oriented manifolds, with $Y$ also being connected, and $F: X → Y$ be a smooth map. Clearly, the degree $\deg{F}$ of $F$ is well-defined.
>
> Let $N ⊂ Y$ be a smooth, closed, connected and oriented submanifold and suppose $M ≔ F^{-1}(N)$ is a smooth oriented submanifold, too. Assume $\DeclareMathOperator{\img}{img} \img{DF} ⊄ TN$ everywhere on $M$. Then $M$ is canonically oriented (so the degree of $\tilde{F} ≔ F|_M: M → N$ is well-defined) and $\deg{\tilde{F}} = \deg{F}$.

(Note that the assumption $\img{DF} ⊄ TN$ rules out the counterexample by Jason DeVito.)

The proof rests on a reduction to the case of [my previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3524868/degree-of-a-map-when-restricting-it-to-a-submanifold/3525200#3525200). To
this end, choose any Riemannian metric on $N$ (which exists by a
partition-of-unity argument). By orientability of $N$, there is a unit
normal field $ν$ on $N$ w.r.t. this Riemannian metric. Then for small
enough $ε > 0$,

$$
    U ≔ \{ \exp_y(ν t) \,|\, y ∈ N, t ∈ (-ε, ε) \}
$$

is an open set diffeomorphic to $N × (-ε, ε)$ (i.e. a tubular
neighborhood of $N$) and so

$$
    p: U → ℝ, p(z) = p((y(z), t(z))) ≔ t(z)
$$

is well-defined and smooth. Observe that $N = p^{-1}(0)$ and that for all $y ∈ N$, $t ∈ (-ε, ε)$: $∂_t p(\exp_y(ν t)) = 1$ and hence $dp ≠ 0$. Hence, $0$ is a regular value of $p$. Moreover, for every $x ∈ M = (p ∘ F_U)^{-1}(0))$ the assumption $\img{D_x F} ⊄ T_{F(x)}N$ implies that there exists some $v ∈ T_x X$ such that $⟨D_x F(v), ν⟩ ≠ 0$. Hence $d(p ∘ F_U)(v) = ⟨ν, DF(v)⟩ ≠ 0$, so $0$ is also a regular value of $p ∘ F_U$.

Therefore, the requirements of my previous answer are fulfilled and orientability of $M$ and the formula for degree follow.